# Discord auto-role reaction bot, getting emoji error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I've been digging the web for an answer but couldn't get an answer so just figured it would be best to post here.

I'm using a function to send a message i my rule section on my discord server and when booting the bot i get an error referring to my rection base message and can't put my finger on what is going on.

So here is the error I'm getting :

```
(node:1387) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [EMOJI_TYPE]: Emoji must be a string or GuildEmoji/ReactionEmoji
    at Message.react (/home/runner/La-chouffe/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Message.js:546:23)
    at addReactions (/home/runner/La-chouffe/first-message.js:3:11)
    at /home/runner/La-chouffe/first-message.js:17:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:1387) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1387) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

here is the two files concerned :

role-rglt.js

```
const firstMessage = require('./first-message.js')

module.exports = async (Client) => {
  const channelId = '583212194116665359'

  const getEmoji = emojiName => Client.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === emojiName)

  const emojis = {
    check: 'Les clients',
  };

  const reactions = []

  let emojiText = 'Tout d\'abord bienvenu sur ce serveur discord qui est un serveur communautaire.\n\nVoici quelques règles qu\'il vous sera demandé de respecter pour que votre expérience ici ce passe le mieux possible :\n\n¤ Ici vous avez le choix de votre pseudo tant que nous pouvons mentionner celui-ci et qu\'il ne soit pas choquant.\n\n¤ Le respect des autres est primordial. Pas de violence verbale gratuite s\'il vous plaît. les insultes ne sont pas interdite tant que cela reste de simple taquinerie.\n\n¤ Les propos racistes, sexiste, homophobes, religieux sont a utiliser avec une grande prudence.\n\n¤ Les propos pédophile sont à proscrire et feront l\'objets d\'un ban (sauf dans humour noir, cela est "toléré").\n\n¤ Le flood et le spam écrit comme vocal abusif feront l\'objet d\'une sanction.\n\n¤ La divulgation d\'information personnelle d\'autrui est interdite et fera l\'objet d\'un ban définitif.\n\n¤ Les doubles comptes sont interdit sauf pour le staff.\n\n¤ Merci d\'éviter les fausses plaintes et de ping le staff pour des raisons inutile.\n\n';

  for (const key in emojis) {
    const emoji = getEmoji(key)
    reactions.push(emoji)

    const role = emojis[key]
    emojiText += `Appuyez sur la réaction ${emoji} pour accepter les règles`
  }

  firstMessage(Client, channelId, emojiText, reactions)

  const handleReaction = (reaction, user, add) => {
    if (user.id === '800855759956344832') {
      return
    }

    const emoji = reaction._emoji.name

    const { guild } = reaction.message

    const roleName = emojis[emoji]
    if(!roleName){
      return
    }

    const role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === roleName)
    const roleRm = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "Athée")
    const member = guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user.id)

    if (add) {
      member.roles.add(role)
      member.roles.remove(roleRm)
    }
  }

  Client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelId) {
      handleReaction(reaction, user, true)
    }
  })
  
}
```

first-message.js

```
const addReactions = (message, reactions) => {
  message.react(reactions[0])
  reactions.shift()
  if (reactions.length > 0) {
    setTimeout(() => addReactions(message, reactions), 750)
  }
}

module.exports = async (Client, id, text, reactions = []) => {
  const channel = await Client.channels.fetch(id)

  channel.messages.fetch().then((messages) => {
    if (messages.size === 0) {
      // Send a new message
      channel.send(text).then((message) => {
        addReactions(message, reactions)
      })
    } else {
      // Edit the existing message
      for (const message of messages) {
        message[1].edit(text)
        addReactions(message[1], reactions)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

as of right now I've looked many time and tried many things that have failed only thing is i get the message no problems in discord but no reactions whatsoever

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, take a tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour . And learn how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Never post links or pictures of code, just use ```code tags```.

Comment: If `reactions` is an empty array: `reactions[0]` will be undefined so it's not a correct emoji.

Comment: well reactions is an array where the emojis are .push() into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found a solution for anyone who is interested.

So instead of calling the getEmoji constant inside my loop

```
const getEmoji = (emojiName) => Client.emojis.cache.find((emoji) => emoji.name === emojiName)
```

I'm giving directly the emoji and the id of the role inside my emojis object like this:

```
const emojis = {
  check: 'Les clients', //old method
};

const emojis = {
  '✅': '586261210002096131', //new method
};
```

Then inside my loop i modify how i'm giving the instructions to push the emoji into the message

```
for (const key in emojis) {
  const emoji = getEmoji(key) //old method
  reactions.push(emoji)

  const role = emojis[key] //this line is not used
  emojiText += `Appuyez sur la réaction ${emoji} pour accepter les règles`
}

for (const key in emojis) {
  reactions.push(key) // new method

  emojiText += `Appuyez sur la réaction ${key} pour accepter les règles`
}
```

Finally since i use the id and not the name of the role I'm also modifying the line giving the role to the member

```
const role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === roleName) //old method

const role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.id === roleName) //new method
```

Since I'm using this same exports for a user self choosing role i add a small switch case that replace the id by a name like this (inside the for loop, NOT THE SAME FILE)

```
let role = ''
switch(emojis[key]) {
  case '829739058040799382' :
    role = 'NSFW';
    break;
  case '829777082232864829' :
    role = 'Coin des joueurs';
    break;
  case '829775173179277342' :
    role = 'Actu Scans';      
    break;
  case '829774879049777224' :
    role = 'Actu Animes';      
    break;
  case '829775145874358332' :
    role = 'Actu films/séries';      
    break;
  case '829775281832591382' :
    role = 'Actu jeux-vidéos';      
    break;
}
```

And just like that i have a perfectly working auto-role system, here's two screenshot:

[rules with auto role for giving access to the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeSCF.png)

[self choosing auto role to give access to specific parts of the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg2Kn.png)

In hope that it will help somebody in need :)